# Discussions about Healthy Diet

Tags: sources-mekorot, health-safety-shmira

Do any early Posekim (from around 200 years ago and earlier) other than the Rambam discuss a good diet and healthy lifestyle?

Comment: If they did, it seems like many Jews today have stopped paying attention.

Comment: Are you asking if they discuss the importance of staying healthy or if they give specific directions to do so?

Comment: @DoubleAA specifics of staying healthy.

Answer (score 1):

A large section of the sefer שבילי אמונה by R. Meir Aldavi, a grandson of the Rosh, discusses in great detail this topic. The sefer is available vowelised.